# JMeter, Jetty Performance test and Keep-Alive issues

Tags: jetty, jmeter, keep-alive

Ok, so I created a very simple WAR which serves a simple Hello World .jsp. With all the HTML it's about 200bytes.

Deployed it on my server running Jetty 7.5.x jdk 6u27
On my client computer create simple JMeter test plan with: Thread Group, HTTP Request, Response Assertion, Summary Report Client also running jdk6u27

I set up the thread group to 5 threads running for 60secs and I got 5800 requests/sec
Then I setup 10 threads and got 6800 requests/sec

The moment I disable Keep-Alive in JMeter on the HTTP Request sampler. I seem to get lots of big pauses on the client side I suppose, it doesn't seem the server is receiving anything. I get less pauses at 5 threads or barely none but at 10 threads it hangs pretty much all the time.

What does this mean exactly?

Keep in mind I'm technically creating a REST service and I was getting the same issue, so I though maybe I was doing something funky in my service, till I figured out it's a Keep-Alive issue as it's doing it pretty much on a staic web app. So in reality I will have 1 client request 1 server response. The client will not be keeping the connection open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that since Keep-Alive is what allows HTTP Connection (and thereby, socket) reuse, you are running out of available ephemeral port numbers -- there are only 64k port numbers, and since connections must have unique client/server port combos (and server port is fixed), you can quickly go through those. Now, if ports were reusable as soon as connection was closed by one side, it would not matter: however, as per TCP spec, both sides MUST wait for configurable amount of time (default: 2 minutes) until reuse is considered safe.

For more details you can read a TCP book (like "Stevens book"); above is a simplification.

Comment: Yeah thought so. I set Windows down to 30 seconds. But at 6000 for 30 seconds request per second thats 180 000 connections. I guess I would need to test from multiple client boxes.